# css customize scrollbar size and position

Tags: css, scrollbar

I am trying to create a scrollbar slightly shifted within my component and slightly smaller. Here is what it would look like:
[image]

But I want it to get the entire component scrolled, not just a small part of it which would start at the scrollbar start and end at its end.

Here is what I did:

```css
.box::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width      : 16px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

.box::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #2A2A2A;
    border-radius   : 8px;
}

.box::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #4B4B4B;
    border-radius   : 8px;
}
```

Unfortunately the margin doesn't seem to work:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

scroll bars will always be placed at the borders of the container div

to get around this make a new div and put some padding around it like so

```
<div style='padding: 1rem'>(your HTML)<div>
```

the padding on the parent div will push the scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

you can give padding to the outermost div you created.

```
<div style="padding: 20px;"> </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).